# Setting Frappe Workspace permission for a User Role to only see the workspace

Tags: permissions, roles, frappe

I'm developing a sample web application using Frappe framework, and I'm trying to use the new workspace functionalities to create a User platform.
I'm creating the workspace as an Administrator with various visualization of some sample DocType I've created.
Then i created a Role named "Building Owner" and i want this User Role to see only the created workspace.
Is possible to give access for a Role only to the workspace without giving desk access?
If not what is the best way to limit the desk permission to have the user visualizing only the workspace with the doctype visualization?

Bonus question: How can i differentiate the doctype visualization (adding different filters) in the workspace for each user? I think i need to use Hooks but would be great if someone could give me some examples.

Thanks

For now I've tried to limit the single doctype permission, giving to the role just the read permission but this just limit the Role to not add or delete the selected doctype. But i want to limit more the user.